# How can I prevent a recording from being inadvertently stopped?

Tags: video-recording, audio-recording

After I hit Record on my Android for video or audio recordings, the Stop button is too easily triggered accidentally, e.g. by the wind or physical matter (dust, paper) that manages to touch the phone screen. How can I force the phone to require more than a touch (e.g. a password) to stop or pause a recording?

Comment: Use a recorder that works when  screen is off, for example [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coffeebeanventures.easyvoicerecorder) for audio. With the screen off accidental touches will not trigger stop. Just need to lock screen when recording starts and unlock to stop

Comment: And for video search play store for "secret video recordings" and pick any app that can record with screen off. I didn't try any but going by ratings, this app seems fine https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kimcy929.secretvideorecorder